# How to convert a Json file with twitter data to dataframe in R?

Tags: r

My original file was 70.000 rows, and at least I am one step ahead because I have already read the file.

This is my post-processed file with Twitter data, I only include the header and 10 rows, and I am wondering how to continue spliting one column to n-columns.

[Link to my github repository with a sample of the original file](https://github.com/frm1789/LittleWomen/blob/master/example.csv)

1. Original file: a cvs file with 10 rows and 1 column
2. Expected result: a dataframe with columns for each value.

I tried with
1. RJSONIO, error
2. tdyr 
3. a mix between data.frame and matrix
4. readLines

I am wondering which is the correct way to tackle this problem.

Comment: It's likely more efficient to read the whole thing from JSON directly into R all at once. Most everybody seems to use `jsonlite::fromJSON` these days, though there are both older and newer alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, I will read more carefully the documentation from jsonlite package in order to read all the file completely.