# Convert Json data from a rows into a dataframe to a dataframe

Tags: python, r

I have a dataframe with json data for each row:

```
{"created_at":"Fri Jun 15 04:58:37 +0000 2018","id":1007487521368965122,"id_str":"1007487521368965122","text":"RT @PulseNigeria247: ICYMI: A psychic pig has predicted that the Super Eagles will get to the semi-final of the #Worldcup tournament and he\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":44664567,"id_str":"44664567","name":"JustJude","screen_name":"egbas","location":"lagos","url":null,"description":"Nigeria on my mind. Words follow me. Editor at Pulse. Writer","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":27850,"friends_count":2861,"listed_count":57,"favourites_count":901,"statuses_count":85945,"created_at":"Thu Jun 04 17:13:53 +0000 2009","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/995218836701040640\/GTweYH_b_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/995218836701040640\/GTweYH_b_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/44664567\/1493675536","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Fri Jun 15 00:00:00 +0000 2018","id":1007412369872613376,"id_str":"1007412369872613376","text":"ICYMI: A psychic pig has predicted that the Super Eagles will get to the semi-final of the #Worldcup tournament and\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/0f8TuzpC5y","display_text_range":[0,140],"source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/studio.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eMedia Studio\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":374999591,"id_str":"374999591","name":"Pulse Nigeria","screen_name":"PulseNigeria247","location":null,"url":"http:\/\/onelink.to\/8htt77","description":"Download #PulseBuzz from your Mobile App Store now. Click link below\ud83d\udcf1\u27a1\ufe0f http:\/\/onelink.to\/8htt77","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":54992,"friends_count":1243,"listed_count":268,"favourites_count":5301,"statuses_count":116888,"created_at":"Sat Sep 17 10:03:37 +0000 2011","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"la
```

The complete structure has this form:

[image]
The original file in raw is: 
     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frm1789/LittleWomen/master/test.csv

The name of the columns into the " are:

```
"created_at"  
"id"
"id_str"
"text"
"source"
"truncated"
"in_reply_to_status_id"
"in_reply_to_status_id_str"
"in_reply_to_user_id":null,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
"user"
"id"
"id_str"
"name"
"screen_name"
"location"
"url"
"description"
"translator_type"
"protected"
"verified"
"followers_count"
"friends_count"
"listed_count"
"favourites_count"
"statuses_count"
"created_at"
"utc_offset"
"time_zone":
"geo_enabled"
"lang":"
"contributors_enabled"
"is_translator"
"profile_background_color"
"profile_background_image_url"
"profile_background_image_url_https"
"profile_background_tile"
"profile_link_color"
"profile_sidebar_border_color"
"profile_sidebar_fill_color"
"profile_text_color"
"profile_use_background_image"
"profile_image_url"
"profile_image_url_https"
"profile_banner_url"
"default_profile"
"default_profile_image"
"following"
"follow_request_sent"
"notifications"
"geo"
"coordinates"
"place"
"contributors"
"retweeted_status"
```

The expected result is a dataframe with the same quantity of rows, but instead with one column, with all the columns.

For now, I didn't know how to move on, without obtain or a empty list or a empty dataframe contains just factors. 
I am also considering to check with Python, in order to see if there is a simpler way to make the conversion.

Thank you,

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862411/how-to-convert-a-json-file-with-twitter-data-to-dataframe-in-r

Comment: Because now I discovered that the first line was corrupted and for that reason any previos idea fails, and second I think that a possible solution is to figured out how to say to R that I know the name of each possible columns and the "string" after the name of the column is the content of my posible column. If you think that this idea is terrible.. it is ok.

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: I am using R for now, but if you think that Pandas could be helpful and you recommend that, I am moving to Panda.